# Error while execute java procedure from Oracle Database

Tags: java, plsql, oracle19c, pkcs#11

I have java code to read certificate from USB token. The code is working properly as stand alone Java class.

After importing Java class into Oracle Database (19c), with *loadjava* utility, the Java class is imported successfully but after execution it gives the below error:

> java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found

The above error means the security provider not added. In the stand alone Java class, to fix this error, just add the following line to *java.security* file in Java directory:

```
security.provider.13=SunPKCS11 configration_file.cfg
```

I also added the above line to *java.security*, in *javavm* folder, in the database home but that didn't fix the error.

The used Java code is:

```java
class GetSignatureNew {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GetSignatureNew sdk = new GetSignatureNew();
    }

    public static String GetSignatureFun(String serialized)
    {
        String pwd = "*******";
        char[] pin = new char[pwd.length()]; 
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
                pin[i] = pwd.charAt(i);
            }
            
            // Get Certificate and private key from token
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
            ks.load(null, pin);
            Enumeration enu = ks.aliases();
            String alias = String.valueOf(enu.nextElement());           
            X509Certificate cert =  (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
            PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pin);
            byte [] output = cert.getEncoded();         
            String b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);
            return b64;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody has an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Execute Java Procedure
the output is not correct because it gives

"java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found"

Comment: If you uploaded the code to the server, it executes in the context of the server hardware, not your client.  It's unclear what you're expecting should happen here.

Comment: Sure, the stand alone Java code executed successfully on the server itself

Comment: [10.2.5 Customizing the Default java.security Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/database-contents-Oracle-JVM-security.html#GUID-F8F1FB30-8FFC-4866-BE9D-43FB97FCF4AA) in _Java Developer's Guide_ which is part of Oracle 19c database documentation.

Comment: Dear Abra, Thanks for your response. I  loaded java.security file but still same error

Comment: @Abra I think the mentioned link for 10g Database, by the way after doing the steps listed in the link i select the following from database SELECT object_name,status,sharing FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE LIKE 'JAVA%'
and object_type='JAVA RESOURCE'
and lower(object_name) like '%lib/security/java.security%'; and the results was lib/security/java.security VALID METADATA LINK
lib/security/java.security.alt VALID NONE

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I tried to create a schedule job on oracle to run batch and this batch will run java code.
Unfortunately, when i run the batch the batch is run successfully but if i run the oracle job it run with error also

```
   STANDARD_ERROR="java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:878)
    at GetSignatureDB.main(GetSignatureDB.java:102)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuc"
```

Schedule Job

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB( job_name => 'einvoice_signature_job',
        job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe',
        job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
        comments => 'Job to call batch script on Windows',
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        number_of_arguments => 3,
        enabled => FALSE);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'einvoice_signature_job', argument_position => 1, argument_value => '/q'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'einvoice_signature_job', argument_position => 2, argument_value => '/c'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'einvoice_signature_job', argument_position => 3, argument_value => '"E:\Backup\eInvoice\GetCert.bat"'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE( 'einvoice_signature_job' ); 
END;
/
```

batch file

```
cd E:\Backup\eInvoice
E:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java" GetSignatureNew
```

which GetSignatureNew  is the java class listed in the original post.

the batch works fine if i run it manually.

but when i run the Oracle job

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB ('einvoice_signature_job');
END;
```

it runs and return the above error